# Ksp multiplatform redeclaration of files

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-symbol-processing

I am implementing `ksp processor` in kotlin multiplatform targeting iOS and android applications, following documentation I'm defining multiple configuration names for KSP ie:

```
add("kspIosArm64", project(":test-processor"))
add("kspIosX64", project(":test-processor"))
```

However running those gives me file redeclaration error. Indeed files are created in separate locations:
`build/generated/ksp/iosArm64/` and `build/generated/ksp/iosX64/` but packages are the same.

And Im quite lost how to solve this issue, is there any way of getting this generated folder path for each generated file so that `package` can be modified?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to partially answer your questions right now, not to make you stack and focus on making the project able to run. I assume that you are using XCode to run the project for iOS. The problem here is that (as you mentioned) all of those source sets are being generated with the same package name which is more a KSP issue (I think) that we have to wait for to be solved.

What you can do for now to run and test the project is:

1. Make sure to clean your build with `./gradlew clean` before running the project (especially between Android and iOS runs)

I think `clean` can be added as a "step" before `KMM` framework task:

XCode Project file -> Build Phases -> Generate KMM framework -> add `clean` before running gradle task responsible for building framework (This can will make build time longer)

`./gradlew :yourSharedModule:clean :yourSharedModuleName:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode`

2. Selected only one architecture to be build when running the project

XCode Project -> Build Settings -> Architectures -> Build Active Architecture Only -> Yes

This solutions makes only one architecture to be build and run (it is probably a simulator in your case), issue here is you may have some problems with other architectures and will not be able to spot them easily on daily development.

3. Create some kind of `env` or a build config value to distinguish which `ksp` dependency to add (based on it's value) so not all of processors are added when running the project

XCode Project -> Build Phases -> Generate KMM framework -> pass it as gradle param `-Parchitecture=someArchitecture`

Or maybe it is even possible to do it within the `build.gradle.kts` file

4. Manually comment out some of `ksp` dependencies (iOS ones) so the only one against which you are building is left (remember to sync project and clean it)

**I personally would try to implement the third solution, I do not know whether it is easy, but it seems to be the best one, other solutions should also work, but please consider them as a dirty walk-around.**

I can provide more info or some kind of POC for that later, just let me know in the comments or somewhere else whether it is needed.